# How can I refer to the output of a test file when writing a script?

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to be able to define the "deposit" variable to result in different outputs based on the previous line of the output.

For example, if the previous output of the code is:

```
Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained. Account is frozen
```

I want any future deposits to have no impact on the balance, and to print:

```
Sorry, account frozen
```

Here is my code:

```
class MinimumBalanceAccount:
    def __init__(self,account_number,holder_name,min_balance):
        self.account_number = account_number
        self.holder_name = holder_name
        self.balance = 0
        self.min_balance = 200

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        if self.balance < self.min_balance:
            print("Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained. Account is frozen") 
            self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        if self.balance - amount < self.min_balance and self.balance - amount != 0:
            print("Sorry, account frozen.")
            self.balance -= amount  
        return self.balance + amount
```

I expect the output to read:

```
Account: FR646 Paul
Depositing 500
Withdrawing 180
Withdrawing 180
Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained. Account is frozen
Depositing 500
Sorry, account frozen.
Balance: 320
```

Whereas, what I currently see is:

```
Account: FR646 Paul
Depositing 500
Withdrawing 180
Withdrawing 180
Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained. Account is frozen
Depositing 500
Balance: 820
```

Comment: Are these two functions in a class? If so, you should edit your code to show this.

Comment: How are you calling these 2 functions?  How are you creating the "Account" objects?

Comment: How does the account get *unfrozen*?  Also, do your checks *before* updating `self.balance`, to save yourself the trouble of adjusting the balance after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

I think your two functions are inside a class. Since you didn't show the class, I am going to call it `Account`. Note that the `self` variable will always be an instance of this class. You can add any field you wish to it. For example, you can do `self.locked = True` to indicate that the account is locked. Be sure that you also include a `__init__()` method to initialize `self.locked` to an appropriate value.